# How to set the default value for existing entries when adding a new column?

Tags: django, django-1.7

I have a model in my Django app that requires a new `BooleanField`column to be added. This column should never be null - instead, I'd like all the existing entries to set this field to `False`.

How do I do that? If I just add the new field and set `default = False`, it'll cause an `OperationalError: no such column` error.

Comment: I believe `manage.py migrate` handles this case and sets the default for you, have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Django's migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/), which will allow you to add the field to the database.

In short, you make the change to your model, create a migration with `manage.py makemigrations`, and then run it with `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: This does work if I remove all the existing rows first. However, it doesn't work when I have existing rows in the table. It causes the error I mentioned.

Comment: When do you get that error? When you run ``makemigrations`` or ``migrate``?

Comment: After running those and trying to access the table in the Django admin panel. `makemigrations` says "no changes detected" when I add the new field.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to migrate your database after adding the new column. Its like when you use the syncdb command to do the "create table" commands when first creating your database, the migrations will write "alter table" changes to your database.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

Comment: I did run the migration commands just as usual, but the existing rows are not affected. The only way I know how to solve this is to remove all the existing rows, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Did you do an initial migration on the app?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had missed that the migrate command requires the app name. So, I had to run the command like this:

```
manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

Comment: The app name is only required if there aren't any migrations yet. This is to prevent that migrations are generated accidentally if an app doesn't want migrations.

Answer (score -1):

By default `BooleanField` column is False, you don't need to specify anything. Just run `python manage.py migrate`. It should work.